# Ruby date range includes a specific day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

If I have two dates ie.

```
checkin = Date.parse('params[:checkin])
checkout = Date.parse('params[:checkout])
```

How can I check to see if between those two dates there is a Monday?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  (checkin..checkout).any?(&:monday?)
```

Also, I'm not sure if Range#any? instantiates an array or not. <s>Just in case if it does, it would be better to add additional check in order to avoid high memory consumption</s> (*see update below*):

```
  checkout - checkin > 7 || (checkin..checkout).any?(&:monday?)
```

And also make sure that checkin is <= checkout.

UPD: I've just double-checked. There is no need check if `checkout - checkin` greater than something. `Range#any?` is smart enough and does not create an array internally (at least, in ruby 1.9.3):

```
1.9.3p327 :004 > checkin, checkout = Date.new, Date.new + 9000.years
=> [Mon, 01 Jan -4712, Sun, 01 Jan 4288]

1.9.3p327 :005 > `ps -o vsize= #{$$}`.strip.to_i
 => 3161660   # memory usage of the current process 

1.9.3p327 :006 > (checkin..checkout).any?(&:monday?)
 => true
1.9.3p327 :007 > `ps -o vsize= #{$$}`.strip.to_i
 => 3161660   # memory usage of the current process stays the same

1.9.3p327 :008 > (checkin..checkout).to_a.any?(&:monday?) # force .to_a
 => true
1.9.3p327 :009 > `ps -o vsize= #{$$}`.strip.to_i
 => 3421680   # memory usage increases and also the previous line was very slow
```

Comment: You can improve your 2nd statement to `checkout - checkin > 5` or `checkout - checkin >= 6`.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is awsum, 
`(checkin..checkout).any?(&:monday?)`,

but you can also do as follow,

```
(checkin..checkout).cover?(Date.today) # you can give date to it.
```

Just for FYI, @DNNX  and Aleks, we have to Date as a parameter to cover as we are applying it on DateRange.